# In a WMI provider, how to get the caller's login name, fqdn, and IP address?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, wmi

I'm developing a WMI provider and would like to know who is accessing my methods. Information about the caller I'm looking for is login name, fqdn, and IP address. This seems to be pretty straightforward in most web frameworks, but I can't seem to find this kind of information for WMI.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to implement your own access control system, instead of using the tried-and-tested one provided by WMI (and the OS it runs on). See [Impersonating a Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390870.aspx) for information.

Comment: Not trying to implement my own access control. Will still rely on permissions applied to namespace. Just want to log who is calling and from where.